# Align Equations with keeping Equation Numbering?

Tags: equations, align, numbering, amsmath

I am trying to write more than one equation with numbering, but when using the `\begin{align}` instead of `\begin{equation}` the numbering disappears. Here are my equations with some split in two lines.
I have searched for similar questions to my question but I couldn't solve the issue.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx} %
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
%-------------------this is part from chapter 3 ------ 
    %objective eq1
    \begin{equation}
    \label{eq:3.1}
    Min \quad \sum_{i=1}^{N} \sum_{s=1}^{C} \sum_{r=1}^{H} \sum_{k=1}^{G} \sum_{t=1}^{T} y_{isrk}^{t} 
    \end{equation}
    Subjected to:
    %eq2
    \begin{equation}
    \label{eq:3.2}
    \vert{p_i}-\sum_{s=1}^{C} \sum_{r=1}^{H} \sum_{k=1}^{G} \sum_{t=1}^{T} v_{isrk}^{t}\vert{} \leq \delta,\qquad\forall{i}\in\{{1,\ldots,N}\} \end{equation}
    %eq3
    \begin{equation} \label{eq:3.3} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \sum_{s=1}^{C} \sum_{r=1}^{H} \sum_{k=1}^{G}  v_{isrk}^{t} \leq{L},\qquad 
    \forall {t} \in {\{{1,\ldots,T}\}} \end{equation}
    %eq4
    \begin{equation}\label{eq:3.4} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \sum_{s=1}^{C} \sum_{r=1}^{H}v_{isrk}^{t} +\sum_{i=1}^{N} \sum_{s=1}^{C} \sum_{r=1}^{H}x_{isrk}^{t} \leq{1},\qquad \forall {t} \in {\{{1,\ldots,T}\}} \end{equation}
    %eq5
    \begin{equation} \label{eq:3.5}
        \begin{multlined}
        \sum_{i=1}^{N} x_{isrk}^{t} \leq \sum_{i=1}^{N}(u_{isrk}^{t}-u_{is(r+1)k}^{t}),\\ \qquad \forall {s} \in {\{{1,\ldots,C}\}},{r} \in {\{{1,\ldots,H-1}\}},
        {k} \in {\{{1,\ldots,G}\}},{t} \in {\{{1,\ldots,T}\}}    
        \end{multlined}
    \end{equation} 
    %eq6
    \begin{equation}\label{eq:3.6}
        \begin{multlined}
        {\sum_{s^{'}=1 {,{s^{'}\neq s}}}^{N} \sum_{r=1}^{H} y_{i{s^{'}rk}}^{t}} \geq {\sum_{r=1}^{H}x_{isrk}^{t}},\\ \qquad \forall {i} \in {\{{1,\ldots,N}\}},{s} \in {\{{1,\ldots,C}\}},
        {k} \in {\{{1,\ldots,G}\}},{t} \in {\{{1,\ldots,T}\}}    
        \end{multlined}
    \end{equation} 
    %eq7
    \begin{equation}\label{eq:3.7}
        \begin{multlined}
        \sum_{i=1}^{N} v_{isrk}^{t} + \sum_{i=1}^{N} y_{isrk}^{t} +\sum_{i=1}^{N} x_{isrk}^{t} \leq {1}, \\ \qquad \forall {s} \in {\{{1,\ldots,C}\}},{r} \in {\{{1,\ldots,H}\}},{k} \in {\{{1,\ldots,G}\}},{t} \in {\{{1,\ldots,T}\}}    
        \end{multlined}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thank you all for your comments, I have tried the following and It worked. Now the equations are aligned to the left side of the page.

```
    \documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{siunitx} %
    \usepackage{textcomp}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \begin{document}
        %-------------------this is part from chapter 3 ------ 
    \begin{align}
    %objective eq1
    &\text{Objective:} \nonumber \\
    & Min \quad \sum_{i=1}^{N} \sum_{s=1}^{C} \sum_{r=1}^{H} \sum_{k=1}^{G} \sum_{t=1}^{T} y_{isrk}^{t}\label{eq:3.1} \\ 
    &\text{Subjected to} \nonumber \\
    %eq2
    &\vert{p_i}-\sum_{s=1}^{C} \sum_{r=1}^{H} \sum_{k=1}^{G} \sum_{t=1}^{T} v_{isrk}^{t}\vert{} \leq \delta,\qquad\forall{i}\in\{{1,\ldots,N}\}\label{eq:3.2}\\
    &\begin{multlined}
    \sum_{i=1}^{N} x_{isrk}^{t} \leq \sum_{i=1}^{N}(u_{isrk}^{t}-u_{is(r+1)k}^{t}),\\ \qquad \forall {s} \in {\{{1,\ldots,C}\}},{r} \in {\{{1,\ldots,H-1}\}},
    {k} \in {\{{1,\ldots,G}\}},{t} \in {\{{1,\ldots,T}\}}   
    \end{multlined}\label{eq:3.3}\\%eq3
    &\sum_{i=1}^{N} \sum_{s=1}^{C} \sum_{r=1}^{H}v_{isrk}^{t} +\sum_{i=1}^{N} \sum_{s=1}^{C} \sum_{r=1}^{H}x_{isrk}^{t} \leq{1},\qquad \forall {t} \in {\{{1,\ldots,T}\}}\label{eq:3.4}\\%eq4 
    &\begin{multlined} 
    \sum_{i=1}^{N} x_{isrk}^{t} \leq \sum_{i=1}^{N}(u_{isrk}^{t}-u_{is(r+1)k}^{t}),\\ \qquad \forall {s} \in {\{{1,\ldots,C}\}},{r} \in {\{{1,\ldots,H-1}\}},{k} \in {\{{1,\ldots,G}\}},{t} \in {\{{1,\ldots,T}\}}\end{multlined}\label{eq:3.5}\\%eq5
    &\begin{multlined}
    {\sum_{s^{'}=1 {,{s^{'}\neq s}}}^{N} \sum_{r=1}^{H} y_{i{s^{'}rk}}^{t}} \geq {\sum_{r=1}^{H}x_{isrk}^{t}},\\ \qquad \forall {i} \in {\{{1,\ldots,N}\}},{s} \in {\{{1,\ldots,C}\}},{k} \in {\{{1,\ldots,G}\}},{t} \in {\{{1,\ldots,T}\}}\end{multlined}\label{eq:3.6} \\ %eq6 
    &\begin{multlined}
    \sum_{i=1}^{N} v_{isrk}^{t} + \sum_{i=1}^{N} y_{isrk}^{t} +\sum_{i=1}^{N} x_{isrk}^{t} \leq {1},\\ \qquad \forall {s} \in {\{{1,\ldots,C}\}},{r} \in {\{{1,\ldots,H}\}},{k} \in {\{{1,\ldots,G}\}},{t} \in {\{{1,\ldots,T}\}}\end{multlined}\label{eq:3.7}\\%eq7
    & u_{isr1}^{1}=I_{isr},\qquad \forall {i} \in {\{{1,\ldots,N}\}}, {s} \in {\{{1,\ldots,C}\}},{r} \in {\{{1,\ldots,H}\}}\label{eq:3.8}\\
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `\begin{align} instead of \begin{equation} the numbering disappears`, there are no `align` in your example

Comment: Thanks @daleif , I tried \begin{align} and it worked, Please, give a comment on this if you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer use the specific package `optidef`: a LaTeX library for optimization problems with the `[short]` option (with the short code) and without it.

I have cleaned a bit your preamble deleting the `\usepackage{amsmath}` and leaving `\usepackage{mathtools}` that is a *supremum* package.  I have used:

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{parskip}
```

just to have an equilibrium for the `a4paper` and to have not the indent space to begin of a paragraph. Using the option `mini!` you create the subequations and without `!` you have a only numbered equation. In addition I have used other specific commands like `\lvert` and `\rvert`, typical to create `\abs` command.

---

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[short]{optidef}
\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}
Objective:
\begin{mini!}
{}{\sum_{i=1}^{N} \sum_{s=1}^{C} \sum_{r=1}^{H} \sum_{k=1}^{G} \sum_{t=1}^{T} y_{\textup{isrk}}^{t} \protect \label{eq:3.1}}{}{}
\addConstraint {\lvert p_i-\sum_{s=1}^{C} \sum_{r=1}^{H} \sum_{k=1}^{G} \sum_{t=1}^{T} v_{\textup{isrk}}^{t}\rvert}{\leq \delta,}{\quad\forall{i}\in\{{1,\ldots, N}\}}
\addConstraint { \text{left side} }{=\text{right side},}{\quad \forall{i}\in\{{1,\ldots,N}\}}
\end{mini!}    

\begin{mini}
{}{\sum_{i=1}^{N} \sum_{s=1}^{C} \sum_{r=1}^{H} \sum_{k=1}^{G} \sum_{t=1}^{T} y_{\textup{isrk}}^{t} \protect \label{eq:3.2}}{}{}
\addConstraint {\lvert p_i-\sum_{s=1}^{C} \sum_{r=1}^{H} \sum_{k=1}^{G} \sum_{t=1}^{T} v_{\textup{isrk}}^{t}\rvert}{\leq \delta,}{\quad\forall{i}\in\{{1,\ldots, N}\}}
\addConstraint { \text{left side} }{=\text{right side},}{\quad \forall{i}\in\{{1,\ldots,N}\}}
\end{mini}    

\end{document}
```

[image]

Deleting the option `[short]`, you will have the full words (minimize and subject to):

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{optidef}
\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}
Objective:
\begin{mini!}
{}{\sum_{i=1}^{N} \sum_{s=1}^{C} \sum_{r=1}^{H} \sum_{k=1}^{G} \sum_{t=1}^{T} y_{\textup{isrk}}^{t} \protect \label{eq:3.1}}{}{}
\addConstraint {\lvert p_i-\sum_{s=1}^{C} \sum_{r=1}^{H} \sum_{k=1}^{G} \sum_{t=1}^{T} v_{\textup{isrk}}^{t}\rvert}{\leq \delta,}{\quad\forall{i}\in\{{1,\ldots, N}\}}
\addConstraint { \text{left side} }{=\text{right side},}{\quad \forall{i}\in\{{1,\ldots,N}\}}
\end{mini!}    

\begin{mini}
{}{\sum_{i=1}^{N} \sum_{s=1}^{C} \sum_{r=1}^{H} \sum_{k=1}^{G} \sum_{t=1}^{T} y_{\textup{isrk}}^{t} \protect \label{eq:3.2}}{}{}
\addConstraint {\lvert p_i-\sum_{s=1}^{C} \sum_{r=1}^{H} \sum_{k=1}^{G} \sum_{t=1}^{T} v_{\textup{isrk}}^{t}\rvert}{\leq \delta,}{\quad\forall{i}\in\{{1,\ldots, N}\}}
\addConstraint { \text{left side} }{=\text{right side},}{\quad \forall{i}\in\{{1,\ldots,N}\}}
\end{mini}    

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum 1**: Just after the comment of nice user @Zarko I have put another row *to write long condition which OP put in separate lines in equations*.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{optidef}
\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}
Objective:
\begin{mini!}
{}{\sum_{i=1}^{N} \sum_{s=1}^{C} \sum_{r=1}^{H} \sum_{k=1}^{G} \sum_{t=1}^{T} y_{isrk}^{t} \protect \label{eq:3.1}}{}{}
\addConstraint{\lvert p_i-\sum_{s=1}^{C} \sum_{r=1}^{H} \sum_{k=1}^{G} \sum_{t=1}^{T} v_{isrk}^{t}\rvert}{\leq \delta,}{\qquad\forall{i}\in\{1,\ldots, N\}}
\addConstraint{\sum_{i=1}^{N} x_{isrk}^{t}\leq \sum_{i=1}^{N}(u_{isrk}^{t}-u_{is(r+1)k}^{t}),\protect \label{eq:3.3}}{\quad}{\quad\begin{matrix}
     \forall s \in \{1,\ldots,C\},\\
      r \in \{1,\ldots, H-1\}, \\
      k \in \{1,\ldots,G\}, \\
      t \in \{1,\ldots,T\} 
\end{matrix}}
\end{mini!}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

*The other equations can be added using a mechanism of the same design.*

**Addendum 2:** Given the request of *@A Azab* as by comment the `\addConstraint` have almost 3 arguments. I have done several tests and in the first argument you can't split the equations like in your code. But in the third argument you can achieve your request with some unrefined and rough tricks.

`\addConstraint{first argument}{second argument}{third argument}`

See the part:

```
\addConstraint{
        \sum_{i=1}^{N} v_{isrk}^{t} + \sum_{i=1}^{N} y_{isrk}^{t} +\sum_{i=1}^{N} x_{isrk}^{t}}{\leq 1}{\begin{matrix}
        & \\[3.5em]
       \hspace{-5cm} \forall i\in \{1,\ldots,N\}, s \in \{1,\ldots,C\},r \in\{1,\ldots,H\}\protect\label{eq:3.8}
        \end{matrix}}
```

---

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{optidef}
\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}
Objective:
\begin{mini!}
{}{\sum_{i=1}^{N} \sum_{s=1}^{C} \sum_{r=1}^{H} \sum_{k=1}^{G} \sum_{t=1}^{T} y_{isrk}^{t} \protect \label{eq:3.1}}{}{}
\addConstraint{\lvert p_i-\sum_{s=1}^{C} \sum_{r=1}^{H} \sum_{k=1}^{G} \sum_{t=1}^{T} v_{isrk}^{t}\rvert}{\leq \delta,}{\qquad\forall{i}\in\{1,\ldots, N\}}
\addConstraint{
    \sum_{i=1}^{N} v_{isrk}^{t} + \sum_{i=1}^{N} y_{isrk}^{t} +\sum_{i=1}^{N} x_{isrk}^{t}}{\leq 1}{\begin{matrix}
    & \\[3.5em]
   \hspace{-5cm} \forall i\in \{1,\ldots,N\}, s \in \{1,\ldots,C\},r \in\{1,\ldots,H\}\protect\label{eq:3.8}
    \end{matrix}}
\end{mini!}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice answer (of course +1), however I wonder how you would suggest to write long condition which OP put in separate lines in  equations?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't upvote twice :-). Good solution!

Comment: @Zarko LOL :-) ahahahahahhaha. There is not absolutely problem. My best regards to a very nice user.

Comment: Thanks, @Sebastiano , this is Awesome. it worked well.  However, how I can split the long constraint in the same form as my equations in my question; so that the split part start from a new line under the main constraint instead of the matrix form?

Comment: @AAzab Hi, please, can you see the Addendum 2 if it corresponds to your request?